How to implement a determinate progress bar using the Radzen Progress Bar component
I'm new to Blazor, and I tried implementing Radzen's progress bar but I'm not sure what's the proper way to update the progress of the progress bar in my parent component. I'm also using purely Blazor interactive server at the moment.
RadzenProgressBar.razor
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Radzen.Blazor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// RadzenProgressBar component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>
    /// &lt;RadzenProgressBar @bind-Value="@value" Max="200" /&gt;
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public partial class RadzenProgressBar
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override string GetComponentCssClass()
        {
            var classList = new List<string>()
            {
                "rz-progressbar"
            };

            switch (Mode)
            {
                case ProgressBarMode.Determinate:
                    classList.Add("rz-progressbar-determinate");
                    break;
                case ProgressBarMode.Indeterminate:
                    classList.Add("rz-progressbar-indeterminate");
                    break;
            }
            
            classList.Add($"rz-progressbar-{ProgressBarStyle.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()}");

            return string.Join(" ", classList);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the template.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The  template.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment Template { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the mode.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The mode.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public ProgressBarMode Mode { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the unit.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The unit.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public string Unit { get; set; } = "%";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The value.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public double Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the minimum value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The minimum value.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public double Min { get; set; } = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the maximum value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The maximum value.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public double Max { get; set; } = 100;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether value is shown.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><c>true</c> if value is shown; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public bool ShowValue { get; set; } = true;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value changed callback.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The value changed callback.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public Action<double> ValueChanged { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the progress bar style.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The progress bar style.</value>
        [Parameter]
        public ProgressBarStyle ProgressBarStyle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Progress in range from 0 to 1.
        /// </summary>
        protected double NormalizedValue => Math.Min(Math.Max((Value - Min) / (Max - Min), 0), 1);
    }
}

ParentComponent.razor
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor

@page "/"

<div class="rz-m-12">
    <RadzenProgressBar @bind-Value="@value" min="0" max="100"/>
</div>

@code
{
    double value = 25;
}

Link to Radzen documentation for their Progress Bar
https://blazor.radzen.com/progressbar
And the repo of the source code
https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/master/Radzen.Blazor/RadzenProgressBar.razor.cs

What is exactly the problem you're facing?  <RadzenProgressBar /> component is pretty straightforward. Do you have an issue with the @value not being updated? any compilation error? please add further explanation to your issue, and if you haven't yet, check their examples.

You could try updating the value property properly. so when the value changes it will update your progress bar. below is the sample code:
@page "/"
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor

<div class="rz-m-12">
    <RadzenProgressBar @bind-Value="@value" Min="0" Max="100"/>
    <button class="rz-button rz-button-primary rz-mt-4" @onclick="IncreaseProgress">Increase Progress</button>
    <button class="rz-button rz-button-secondary rz-mt-4" @onclick="ResetProgress">Reset Progress</button>
</div>

@code
{
    double value = 25;

    private void IncreaseProgress()
    {
        if (value < 100)
        {
            value += 10;
        }
    }

    private void ResetProgress()
    {
        value = 0;
    }
}

